# How to make git push to the current remote by default?

Tags: git, branch, git-remote

I've got a repository where some branches are on a public remote, and others on a private remote:

```
origin  git@github.com:name/project (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:name/project (push)
private git@github.com:name/project-private (fetch)
private git@github.com:name/project-private (push)
```

So for example a branch "some-public-feature", will be on the "origin" remote, while "some-private-feature" will be on the "private" remote.

This works fine and things get pushed to the correct repositories. However when I try to push from the private branch, it always displays this message:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push private HEAD:some-private-feature

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push private HEAD
```

So really I need to type `git push private HEAD`, which works fine, but I'm wondering if there's any way to make git do this by default? In other words, "git push" should always push the current branch to the branch of the same name on the remote. Any idea if that can be done?

(Note that I don't have this problem for the public branches - in that case, a simple "git push" works as expected, so I'm not sure what's different)

Comment: You could set your `push.default` to `current`. I have not actually tested this so be sure to try it out first. It will definitely make `git push <remote>` push the current branch name to the given remote, using the same name on both sides, but whether  `git push` without a `<remote>` will push to the current branch's *default* remote (`branch.<branch>.remote`), I'm not sure.

Comment: If that *doesn't* work, and you don't mind retraining your brain/fingers, consider making yourself a command or alias that runs `branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) && git config --get branch.$branch.remote` to get the desired setting.